# Using dates with Cassandra

Tags: datetime, date, cassandra

I've just started my adventure with Cassandra database. I've managed to learn some basics but what I still can't understand is how to work with dates in Cassandra?

So for example in MySQL we have a datetime type for a field and we can query (for example) all fields with creation date less then 2010-01-01. Furthermore we can order the result by creation date field.

How can we achieve the same with Cassandra? How to define the corresponding Column Family and how to query (CQL) it to get the same result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use type [DateType](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/cassandra/cassandra-0.8.1/org/apache/cassandra/db/marshal/DateType.html) to define a column of type DateType in your column family. You should really read this [page](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes), it has description and example how to do range query (that is creationdate < 2010-01-01). For ordering, you can refer to the [SliceRange](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#SliceRange) but this will probably cover in the cassandra client already. You will probably want to look into the cassandra [client](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions) to do the query.

This is a snippet on how to do query in cassandra using hector client.

```
// 2010-01-01
Date date = new Date(1262275200L);

try
{
    getConnection();
    IndexedSlicesQuery<String, String, String> indexedSlicesQuery = HFactory.createIndexedSlicesQuery(keyspace, ss, ss, ss);
    indexedSlicesQuery.setColumnNames("name");          
    indexedSlicesQuery.addLtExpression("timestamp", ByteBufferUtil.string(date_s.toByteBuffer(date)));
    indexedSlicesQuery.addEqualsExpression("searchall", ByteBufferUtil.string(bs.toByteBuffer(true)));
    indexedSlicesQuery.setColumnFamily(column_family);
    indexedSlicesQuery.setStartKey("");
    System.out.println(indexedSlicesQuery.toString());
    QueryResult<OrderedRows<String, String, String>> res = indexedSlicesQuery.execute();


    List<Row<String, String, String>> list = res.get().getList();
    for (Row<?, ?, ?> row : list)
    {
        System.out.println(row.getKey());               
    }

}
```